# Как правильно получить количество записей в таблице. где нет delete_at (Laravel)?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Получаю количество имеющихся записей (для вывода на панель)

```php
class DashboardController extends AdminController
{
    public function dashboard()
    {
        $params = [
            'categoriesCount' => BlogCategory::count(),
            'postsCount' => BlogPost::count(),
            //'bookmarksCount' => BlogBookmark::count(),
            'bookmarksCount' => DB::table('blog_bookmarks')->count(),
            'usersCount' => User::count(),
        ];
        return view('admin.dashboard')->with($params);
    }
}
```

Столкнулся с проблемой, что при запросе `'bookmarksCount' => BlogBookmark::count()` получаю ошибку, так как в таблице отсутствуют поля `'create_at'`, `'deleted_at'` (это связующая таблица, поэтому данных полей, как и поля id смысла создавать не было).

Для получения количества записей в этой таблице использовал `bookmarksCount' => DB::table('blog_bookmarks')->count(),`

Насколько это "правильно" и есть ли метод, который позволяет получить количество записей "напрямую" работая с моделью BlogBookmark (в которой отсутствуют поля 'created_at', 'deleted_at'), а не через фасад DB.

Этот фреймворк стал изучать не так давно, документация постоянно перед глазами. Не один раз пробегался по [eloquent-model-conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), но так и не сообразил правильно ли я сделал? А если не нет, то как сделать правильно.

Будуочень признателен за помощь!

Comment: в моделе `BlogBookmark` добавьте `public $timestamps = false;`

Comment: добавил:

```php
public $timestamps = false;
public $incrementing = false;
```

все равно не робит и вываливается ошибка, что не найдено поле created_at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DB::table('blog_bookmarks')->count()`
очень даже правильный вариант, куда лучше чем `'bookmarksCount' => BlogBookmark::count()`. Единственное лучше это делать в репозитории и потом уже вызывать метод репозитория

Comment: Спасибо! Я просто думал, что пользоваться фасадом DB не лучшая практика и по возможности нужно "общаться с моделью напрямую.

Насчет репозиториев вы правы, сейчас как раз занят его созданием.

Comment: а по поводу пользоваться фасадом, то да, мне тоже так говорили и я это запомнил, хотя есть много опровержений, но на грабли не хочется становится ) проблемы будут только при написании тестов, якобы фасад нельзя мокать. и что б не пользоваться фасадом. Используйте `Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager` вместо `DB`